# Have element behave like position sticky, but take it out of the document flow?

Tags: html, css

This seemed pretty easy to me, but I can't seem to get it working and found no real solution online. I have a page with a header, some content, and a sticky navigation bar, which is displayed as a (collapsed) burger menu on small viewports.

Basically, I want the header to disappear when scrolling down the page, and the sticky navigation bar/burger menu to scroll up below the header and then stay at the top of the page. The burger menu is floating to the right (i did that with flexbox, max-content and margin-left:auto).

Now, I'd like to take the sticky burger menu out of the document's flow in order for it to overlap the content section. This is what I can't get to work. I don't want to use position:fixed, as the burger menu should always stay below the header, and I can't use position:absolute, as the content section is quite long.

I've tried using float:right, but then the content-section and burger menu don't overlap at all. I can't position .sticky-navigation inside .div.content, as the content-section is using display:grid, and the navigation bar is collapsed to the burger menu before the grid is aligned in one column on a smaller breakpoint (as the burger menu would then take up a grid item, right?).

I'm completely clueless to how I can achieve this. I'd like to not use Javascript to achieve this, as it should be possible with just CSS? Also, I'm worried about performance taking a hit, especially on mobile devices. Does anybody have an idea how to get there?

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/alessandrov/pen/JjmaEgr

```css
header {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
}

.sticky-navigation {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  max-width: 8rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 1rem;
}

.content {
  background: green;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 15rem;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>This is the header.</header>
<section class="content-section">
  <div class="sticky-navigation">
    <p class="burger">This is where the burger menu would go</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Big title</h1>
    <p>This is where all of the content would go. Repeated to simulate my page. This is where all of the content would go. Repeated to simulate my page. This is where all of the content would go. Repeated to simulate my page.
    </p>
 
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close using `float:right`. You can add `shape-outside` so that your element doesn't take any place in the flow. `inset(50%)` will create a `0x0` rectangle

```css
header {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
}

.sticky-navigation {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  float: right;
  shape-outside: inset(50%);
  max-width: 8rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 1rem;
}

.content {
  background: green;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<header>This is the header.</header>
<section class="content-section">
  <div class="sticky-navigation">
    <p class="burger">This is where the burger menu would go</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Big title</h1>
    <p>This is where all of the content would go. Repeated to simulate my page. This is where all of the content would go. Repeated to simulate my page. This is where all of the content would go. Repeated to simulate my page.
    </p>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! At first I thought it didn't work, then I tested it with different browsers. It works in Safari, and works _somewhat_ in Firefox (content overlaps only 50%) of the burger menu. However, shape-outside:inset(50%) changes nothing in Chrome and Edge. I don't understand this at all, as caniuse lists shape-outside as compatible with all these browsers, yet this is implemented quite differently (for my usecase)...

Comment: @Alessandro remove the big title for easy testing and you will see it works fine everywhere

Comment: I know it works with this simple example, and it does so with my page in Safari as well. Just not in Chrome or Firefox. I've tried stripping away all kinds of CSS properties to find out why it doesn't. If I don't find the reason, I'll try sharing the actual code from my site - it's just much more code.

Comment: I found out what the issues is. If the sibling element (in the example's case .content) has display:grid, the solution doesn't work in Chromium-based browsers and Firefox. I made another Codepen which shows the issue: https://codepen.io/alessandrov/pen/jOevwxo. I'll have to look for another solution again... or change display: to something else as soon as the full-width navbar collapses :-( I don't think you know any workaround for this?